# Visual Studio Code and Arduino IDE stopped working

Tags: 21.10, desktop-apps

I am running Ubuntu 21.10.  When I first installed Visual Studio Code and Arduino IDE, they both loaded properly.  Now, when I click on them or try to run them from the console, they won't open.  Any suggestions?

For Arduino IDE, the error is:

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblistSerialsj.so.1.4.0: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblistSerialsj.so.1.4.0: undefined symbol: sp_get_port_usb_vid_pid
```

For Visual Studio Code, the error is:

```
/ has 'other' write 40777
```

Answer (score 12):

For Arduino IDE, it looks like you hit bug #1916278 (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/arduino/+bug/1916278).

Running the following two command lines will fix the issue:

```sh
sudo apt install libserialport0 patchelf
sudo patchelf --add-needed /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libserialport.so.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblistSerialsj.so.1.4.0
```

Comment: Confirmed working on Ubuntu 21.10

Comment: Confirmed working on Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Confirmed working on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Comment: confirmed working Xubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Comment: + confirmed on  22.04.1 LTS